# Playing videos from XML file using Youtube API - Actionscript 3

Tags: xml, flash, youtube-api, actionscript-3

I'm trying to embed Youtube videos in my Flash project. So far, I have this working fine, using `loadVideoById` and specifying the ID. What I really want to be able to do is bring in which video to load from an XML file which I have set up. I've tried amending, as below. It loads the player, but doesn't load a video.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Loader;

Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");

var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

myLoader.load(new URLRequest("films.xml"));

myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void
{
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

    var myPlayer:Object; 
    var videoLoader:Loader = new Loader();

    videoLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
    videoLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);

    function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void
    {
        videoHolder.addChild(videoLoader);
        myPlayer = videoLoader.content;
        myPlayer.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
    }

    function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void 
    {
        myPlayer.setSize(264,222);
        myPlayer.loadVideoById(myXML.film.trailer,0);
    }

}
```

And my XML:

```
<films>

<film>
<trailer>F3rLLAFE4uk</trailer>
</film>

</films>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to load the video without using the xml. i.e. by directly hardcoding the filename

Comment: @thewhitelakeofhimalayas - Yes, it works if I hardcode the video file name. What I would like to do is be able to navigate between records from an XML file using buttons (I can do navigation part) I just can't get it to read the location of the video from the XML file.

Comment: Did you try putting a break point in processXML and check the xml data ?